# is it possible for mobile to web authentication using qr code without socket? (Node js/react)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flutter, authentication, qr-code

I am looking for some resourse from where I can get idea of qr based login like whatsapp web and descord. I have read some blog post, articles on how they actually work. But most of them either mention socket.

I was thinking if its possible to make this without using socket?

I would appritiate any ideas and resourses. Thank you.

curretly I have a website built with react, a backend of node js and a mobile app made with flutter.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is preferable to use websocket, however if you don't want to use it you can :

1. The user initiates the login process by clicking a "Login with QR code" button on the website.
2. The website generates a unique temporary authentication code and displays the QR code, which contains the encrypted token.
3. The mobile app reads the QR code and sends a request to the backend API with the token, to validate them with the user connected to the app.
4. The backend API checks if the token is valid, and creates an association with the token and the user connected to the mobile app.
5. After that you can log in with our token on your website by clicking the button "My QR code has been validated"

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I built the system this way. But in the client end I have used interval to get response if the qr is matched or not. So that this flow seems more seamless like websocket. I know its not the best option for a server when there will be huge traffic. but for my one this is okay.